# Converting an @Html.Textbox button to submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert an `@Html.Textbox` image button to `submit` button with the onclick calling a Javascript function but I can't seem to figure out the validation part. I believe it does need to be a submit button.

I am basically trying to get rid of the image but keep the functionality.

Here's what's working today.

```
@Html.TextBox("Next", null, new {type = "image", src = @Url.Content("../App_Themes/icons/button_next.png"), @class = "imgbottom", onclick = "javascript: ValidateSelection ($(\"[name$='selectedItems']:checked\"))"}) 


function ValidateSelection(item) {

if (item == null || item.length == 0) {

    var validationSummary = $('.validation-summary-errors ul');
    if (validationSummary.length > 0 && $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').length == 0) {
        validationSummary.append('<li>' + "Please select at least one item" + '</li>');
    }
    var errors = $("[name='ErrorMessage']");
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        errors.hide();
    }
    var buttonGenerateReport = $("#GenerateReport");
    if (buttonGenerateReport.length > 0) {
        buttonGenerateReport.hide();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

}

Comment: Is this working except the validation part?

Comment: Yes it is. Here's where I'm at currently <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="ValidateSelection (selectedItems.checked)">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" class="imgbottom" onclick="ValidateSelection('selectedItems');">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/App_Themes/icons/button_next.png")" alt="Next" /><br />
    Next
</button>
```

The `"~/"` part of the Url Content string represents your project root, so adjust it to fit your correct file address later.

Or you could just use [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) and replace your image entirely by that. It's size scalable because of CSS and has a simpler syntax.

```
<button type="submit" class="imgbottom" onclick="ValidateSelection('selectedItems');">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Next
</button>
```

Then in your jQuery function:

```
function ValidateSelection(elementName){
    var selectedItems = $("[name='" + elementName + "']:checked");

    if (selectedItems === null || selectedItems.length === 0) {
        var validationSummary = $('.validation-summary-errors ul');

        if (validationSummary.length > 0 && $('.validation-summary-errors ul li').length == 0) {
            validationSummary.append('<li>' + "Please select at least one item" + '</li>');
        }
        var errors = $("[name='ErrorMessage']");
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            errors.hide();
        }
        var buttonGenerateReport = $("#GenerateReport");
        if (buttonGenerateReport.length > 0) {
            buttonGenerateReport.hide();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those changes are still having an issue with the onclick="ValidateSelection($[name=selectedItems]:checked); Here's where I'm at currently <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="ValidateSelection (selectedItems.checked)"> so, how would I convert the ValidateSelection($[name=selectedItems]:checked); to work with what I have?

Comment: I forgot the simple quotes, my bad. I'm adding them now.

Comment: To make your life easier, just send "selectedItems" as a parameter to ValidateSelection instead of the whole selector. Then in your function your write down the selector using the value received.

Comment: I guess I don't follow. There still seems to be an issue with the code above. and this don't work either: <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="ValidateSelection (selectedItems)">

Comment: You need to put single quotes around your string parameter. Something like

`<button type="submit" class="imgbottom" onclick="ValidateSelection('selectedItems');">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Next
</button>`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be calling my function. The button displays fine but clicking does nothing whereas the @Html.Textbox image button will validate if any selectedItems checkboxes have been selected.

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the `ValidateSelection` function to show what's working today. Regrettably your latest suggestion did not work.

Comment: If it worked in the end, please be so kind and check the answer.